# How to get folder root from url?

Tags: php, url

How do you get the root folder from a php file?

For example

> URL: http://localhost/project_name/
>
> Result: return "project_name"

Answer (score 1):

Use the [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function for this

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$urlParse = parse_url($url);

echo $urlParse['hostname'];
```

However, this will only work, if you are using a webserver, for these type of url

> http://www.mydomain.com

If you want this to work on a localhost, add some few lines

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$urlParse = parse_url($url);

$path = explode('/',$urlParse ['path']);
echo $path[1]; //gives project_name in your case
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [dirname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) in php

```
<?php
echo "1) " . dirname("/etc/passwd") . PHP_EOL; // 1) /etc
echo "2) " . dirname("/etc/") . PHP_EOL; // 2) / (or \ on Windows)
echo "3) " . dirname("."); // 3) .
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

what do you want? "\localhost" or "c:\". in this case your document root is localhost. and you can get it by `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`;

Comment: Should only get the folder name without the hostname.. e.g. URL is http://localhost/project_name/index.php I should only get the "project_name"

Comment: ok. Then it would be `substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],0,strrpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],"/"));`

Answer (score -1):

In your index.php (`__FILE__` points to current file)

```
 $dir = dirname(__FILE__)
```

Comment: Not really what he's asking for.  The file has nothing to do with the URL.